# Interop.PowerPoint: как задать левый отступ в маркированном списке?

Tags: c#, office, office-interop, vsto, powerpoint

Есть `VSTO Add-in` проект для `PowerPoint`, который в одной из своих частей делает отрисовку маркированного списка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И теперь необходимо сдвинуть параграф второго уровня `-x` влево, как показано на рисунке.

**Каким параметром этот отступ регулируется?**

Пытаюсь сделать так

`Shape.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[2].LeftMargin = 20`

, но никаких изменений не происходит. Пробовал различные значения, не изменяется, но вот если указать какое-нибудь минусовое значение, то исчезает.

Получается менять этот отступ непосредственно через `XML`, там за это отвечает атрибут `marL` и насколько я понимаю в `Interop.PowerPoint` этому атрибуту соответствует `LeftMargin`, но он почему-то отказывается работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо подключить пространство имен `Microsoft.Office.Core` и использовать `TextFrame2` вместо `TextFrame` (пространство имен `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`). Насколько я понял, последний не совсем корректно работает с презентациями начиная с `PowerPoint 2007`.

Вот пример того, что мне помогло:

```
myShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = 20;
```